# Write data to excel or csv file using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, openpyxl

First off, I am really new to Python. With that said, I am trying to scrape a webpage to see when and where the Shopkins Live shows are being performed so I can map it. Now, before you judge me on the Shopkins - just know it is a project I am doing with my oldest kid who is a huge Shopkins fan.

I originally tried putting the data into a csv file but when I did that it would print individual characters into a column - for instance it would say- d a t e across four columns rather than one column. I tried putting it into brackets writerows([data]) but that didn't work.

I have now tried moving onto writing into excel but am struggling with how to do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. When I run the python code it is outputting what I need in the Shell, but not sure how to transition this to write correctly in Excel.  The following is my code - any help is appreciated:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os, csv, sys, openpyxl
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import contextlib
import re




url = 'http://www.shopkinslive.com/tour'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
wb = load_workbook('Shopkins.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='row'):
    divtext = (div.text)
    ws['A1'].value = divtext  #I know this is what I need to fix but not sure how to do it


    print(divtext)   #This part works correctly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kid is really lucky and I bet he/ she knows it!

For the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.shopkinslive.com/tour'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

tour_date = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col date"})
tour_city = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col city"})
tour_venue = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col venue"})
tour_time = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col time"})


t_date = [' '.join(td.text.split()[1:]) for td in tour_date]
t_city = [' '.join(td.text.split()[1:]) for td in tour_city]
t_venue = [' '.join(td.text.split()[1:]) for td in tour_venue]
t_time = [' '.join(td.text.split()[1:]) for td in tour_time]


df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : t_date, 'City': t_city, 'Venue': t_venue, 'Time': t_time} )

df.to_excel('Shopkins.xlsx')
```

I tried to work around here as I didnot manage to append the dataframe row by row. But here's the idea:

I shall grab all necessary data using BS, put them into separate lists and then merge them into a data frame before exporting to excel file.

Please check out if it meets your needs.

P.s: the `[1:]` part should remove the text in `<strong></strong>` tags provided by the website. So yeah, it's the pattern.

Comment: That is perfect.  Can you just explain a little on how the ' '.join(td.text.split() is working.  Thanks so much for your quick help. We are working on learning python and tableau a bit and will be mapping these and putting various shopkin images as the plotted locations in Tableau. (What he doesn't know is we have tickets for one of the shows!)

Comment: @ShawnSchreier: good to hear that! As for the join and split parts: `td` is each entry in the columns (which comes in the pattern of `<strong>Date </strong> ....` for instance. So `td.text` will extract the text elements between the tags, and then `.split()` (equivalent to `split(' ')` which means split by spaces) chops them up into separate elements contained in a list. The `' '.join` function will piece the list elements together using `' '` as a connecting string.